# Reasignar valor a una variable desde una función

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express

(Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta por este medio, disculpen la ignorancia)

```
    <div id="searching">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Nombre">
            <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="buscar()">
    </div>
```

La idea es pasar el `input` a una consulta `query`:

```
let nombre = "nicolas";

function buscar () {
    let nombre = document.getElementById("user").value;
    console.log(nombre);
    window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
}

const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = $1', [nombre]);
    res.status(200).json(response.rows);
};
```

No sé de qué manera pasar el valor del `input` a la variable del `query`. A la variable del principio **("nicolas")** la puse para testear el `query` y me lo devuelve perfectamente, pero no se cómo cambiarla en función del `input`...

Comment: ayuda porfaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces

```
let nombre = document.getElementById("user").value;
```

Estas buscando en el documento un elemento con un atributo "id" que tenga el valor "user" y guardando ese valor en la variable nombre. En el HTML que has puesto no aparece nada de eso. Seguramente tendrás que hacer algo así:

```
<input id="user" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"/>
```

De esta manera en la variable nombre podrás guardar el contenido de ese elemento input.

Answer (score 0):

no funciona con?

```
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" Nombre">
```

Cuando el elemento input esta dentro de una forma se obtiene por name y en el caso por getelementId necesita por consiguiente id